# Ubuntu 20.* как получить адреса которые получали через DNS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, администрирование, dns

как логировать dns запросы?
если компьютер через браузер или через скрипты обращается к стронним сервисам, то логировать куда именно он обращался, желательно через DNS

Comment: 1. Свой DNS-сервер с записью журнала. 2. Правила сетевого фильтра для записи запросов (не будет тела запроса и ответа, только сам факт). 3. Сбор пакетов чем-то вроде `packetbeat`.

Answer (score 3):

Установи локально dnsmasq  и настрой его как nameserver `sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/use-dnsmasq.conf`

```
[main]
dns=dnsmasq
```

Добавь log-queries `sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/log.conf`

```
log-queries
log-facility=/var/log/nm-dnsmasq.log
```

Лог запросов смотри `tail -f /var/log/nm-dnsmasq.log | grep 'query\[A'`